# Where can I get lock picks?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I'm doing Raedric's Hold, and have gotten to the sanctuary. Sadly, to progress I need to unlock some doors and I'm out of picks. Where can I get more, preferably without travelling too far...

Comment: You don't need picks if your mechanics skill is high enough relative to the lock difficulty as far as I can tell. So raising your mechanics skill would be an alternative to finding lockpicks.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy some in Gilded Vale smithy (Black Hammer Smithy) in eastern part of the village, BUT only after you complete The Smith's Shipment quest. You can also get them as random loot from enemies or lootable places like chests and barrels. But as Mad Scientist wrote it is a lot easier to just boost your Mechanics skill and have no worries over lockpicks at all.